# Fechar Dialog após 10 segundos aberto

Tags: java, android, webview, dialog

Gostaria que o *dialog* fechasse após 10 segundos. Eu só consigo fazer clicando no botão.

Segue o código.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        WebView wv = new WebView (this);
        WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.loadUrl("http://192.168.200.233:8888/Propagandas/Propagandas.html");
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
                return true;
            }
        });

        alert.setView(wv);
        alert.setNegativeButton("Fechar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            alert.show();
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed( this, 2000 );
```

É possível?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

10 Segundos em milissegundos seria `10000`. Veja abaixo um exemplo como seria usando o método `setOnDismissListener()` da sua caixa de diálogo:

**Observação:** Crie uma variável do tipo `Dialog` para receber o seu `alert.show()`, para que você possa usar o método `dimiss()`.

```
... 
//alert.show();
final Dialog dialog = alert.show();

final Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // verificar se a caixa de diálogo está visível
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            // fecha a caixa de diálogo
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
};

alert.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
});

handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);
```

Ai você precisa declarar seu `AlertDialog.Builder` globalmente, fora do `onCreate`. Veja:

```
public AlertDialog.Builder alert;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    // restante do conteúdo
```

Comment: Quando coloco o código, pede para colocar o alert como final e quando coloco fala que método não pode ser aplicado, sabe o que preciso fazer?

Comment: @EduardoSantos declare o alert como Global, fora do onCreate. Só a variável.

Comment: Cannot find symbol method isshowing, isso que aparece.

Comment: Sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: @EduardoSantos fiz uma alteração usando o Dialog. Veja agora, funcionou belezinha aqui comigo. =D

Comment: Muito obrigado, ficou certinho